# Why highest priority threads are displayed with RT in top and htop?

Tags: linux, top, scheduling, htop, priority

In the `top` and `htop` tools, processes (or/and threads depending on display settings) having the highest realtime priority (99 from the userland API point of view) with either the scheduling policy `SCHED_RR` or `SCHED_FIFO` the priority is displayed as `RT`.

For all the other real time processes, the priority is displayed as a number p defined by:

```
p = -userprio -1
```

I am wondering why `top` and `htop` don't display `-100` for higest priority real time processes ?

Comment: I can confirm that `top` and `htop` list four processes with `priority = RT`:  `migration/0` `migragion/1`, `watchdog/0` `watchdog/1` in my case. However, `ps -eo rtprio,comm` lists their priority as `99`.

Comment: Could you add output of `ps -o rtprio,state,pid,comm -A | grep -Ev '^\s+- '`?

Comment: @VolkerSiegel It outputs the realtime priority from the userland API, i.g. 99 for highest rpriority RT processes.

Answer (score 7):

> I am wondering why top and htop don't display -100 for highest priority real time processes ?

That's because `SCHED_RR` and `SCHED_FIFO` have fixed static priorities in the range 1-99:
[RedHat MRG docs on rt](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_MRG/2/html/Realtime_Reference_Guide/chap-Priorities_and_policies.html)

For realtime priorities, the order is reversed: 99 is indeed the highest one, contrary to the usual "lower is higher".

Per your comment I misunderstood your question, sorry.

There is only one column in top, so differentiating the RT priorities from the other ones would not be possible.  To get around this, "rt" is used to indicate that these processes use a realtime scheduler class.

You can see the difference using `ps ax --format uname,pid,ppid,tty,cmd,cls,pri,rtprio`, which will give you 2 columns, one for the prio and the other one for rtprio.

Sidenote: The aforementioned command will also show you the scheduler class the process uses (the `cls` field).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but question was not clear: I am wondering why RT is displayed instead of a number

Comment: Added some more info to my answer.

Comment: Thanks again Jan, but in htop and top only processes with RT prio = 99 are displayed as RT, the other ones even if scheduled with SCHED_FIFO or SCHED_RR are displayed with a number

Comment: I even dug through the code of procps-ng, but I didn't find anything... Waiting for someone else to find the solution.

Comment: In the output of   ps ax --format uname,pid,ppid,tty,cmd,cls,pri,rtprio   in the PRIO column, higher number is higher priority, right? What about the sched classes(CLS), what is: TS, FF, B? Are they CFS, FIFO, BACKGROUND? What are the initials? Thanks